# Merging menustrip items from MDI child into parent's menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a MDI child form which has got some menu options under File tag. Also I have some menu options under the same File tag in the MDI parent form. How to merge the options under the File menu so that they appear under a single File menu when the child form is maximized. I tried the steps given in the following stackoverflow questions but I did not get the desired solution.

[Merge menu strip items for MDI windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511145/merge-menu-strip-items-for-mdi-windows/3513116)

[Merge menu items from MDI child into container's menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991759/merge-menu-items-from-mdi-child-into-containers-menu)

Following the steps given in the above questions, I have two File menus appearing in the menu bar.
[image]

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this solution:

- Set the `MergeAction` property of your mdi child `File` menu to `MatchOnly`
- Set the `Visible` property of the menu strip of your child mdi form to `false`

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution, but the contents of the file menu of child form disappeared

Comment: Probably you have made a mistake when setting property values, the screenshot has taken from that settings. Pay attention to steps and let me know the result:)

Comment: I tried everything still not getting the desired result.

Comment: Sorry. Got it correct now. There was an ambiguity between &File(in child) and File(in parent). Now I changed both to &File and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome, happy to hear that you made it work :)

Comment: Is there a way to set the order of menu items manually after merging

Comment: Yes, there is, you can set `MergeAction` of menu items of your child window to `Insert` and set suitable `MergeIndex` for them.