# MDI Child `MenuStrip` hidden on Non-Maximized and not visible anywhere

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menu, mdi

I have two WinForms. A `frmMainMenu` and a `frmIndividual` with `frmIndividual` a child of `frmMainMenu`. Each window has its own `MenuStrip` in the designer. However at runtime, the child menu does not appear to have a menu strip.

Here is the code creating the child. (It's literally the templated MDI script but modded.)

```
Private Sub IndividualToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IndividualPlayerToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim ChildForm As New frmIndividual
    ' Make it a child of this MDI form before showing it.
    ChildForm.MdiParent = Me

    m_ChildFormNumber += 1
    ChildForm.Text = "(" & m_ChildFormNumber & ") " & ChildForm.Text

    ChildForm.Show()
End Sub
```

I doubled over the follow two questions/answers:

- [Merge menu strip items for MDI windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511145/merge-menu-strip-items-for-mdi-windows/3513116)
- [Merge menu items from MDI child into container's menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991759/merge-menu-items-from-mdi-child-into-containers-menu)

And I can confirm that I do now have a single menu, but the merging of menus happens even when the form isn't maximized.

What am I missing? Why are the menus merging when they weren't supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior, the tool strip manager gets what you set to the merge-related properties in the MDI parent and child forms and strips then acts accordingly. The window state is not a *merge* factor. The [`Form.MainMenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mainmenustrip?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [`ToolStrip.AllowMerge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.allowmerge?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [`ToolStripItem.MergeAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.mergeaction?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties and strip's visibility are.

Now, if you need to hide and merge the `MenuStrip` of the MdiChild Form only when you maximize it, then override its `OnSizeChanged` method to `AllowMerge` and merge the strips when so, otherwise, show the `MenuStrip` and revert the merge. Use the [`ToolStripManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class to manually merge and revert.

```vb
' MDI Child Form
Protected Overrides Sub OnSizeChanged(e As EventArgs) 
    MyBase.OnSizeChanged(e)

    Dim isMax = WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    menuStrip1.AllowMerge = isMax
    menuStrip1.Visible = Not isMax

    If MdiParent?.MainMenuStrip IsNot Nothing Then
        If isMax Then
            ToolStripManager.Merge(menuStrip1, MdiParent.MainMenuStrip)
        Else
            ToolStripManager.RevertMerge(MdiParent.MainMenuStrip)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: SOQ72981652]

Comment: Forgive me as this is a new concept: would I add this Sub on to the tail of the `frmIndividual` class?